# ezxml xml parsing api

Tags: c, api, parsing

How to parse values if I have more than one  tags, like in code above.

```
<formula1>
<team name="McLaren">
<driver>
<name>Abcd</name>
<points>112</points>
</driver>
<driver>
<name>Juan Pablo Montoya</name>
<points>60</points>
</driver>
</team>
</formula1>

<formula1>
<team name="McLaren">
<driver>
<name>Kimi Raikkonen</name>
<points>112</points>
</driver>
<driver>
<name>EFGH</name>
<points>60</points>
</driver>
</team>
</formula1>
```

I was able to print values between tags in first formula1 () with this code example:

```
ezxml_t f1 = ezxml_parse_file("formula1.xml");

printf("%s\n", ezxml_get(f1, "team", 0, "driver", 1, "name", -1)->txt);
ezxml_free(f1);
```

But don't know how to print values from second.

Comment: you need root tag. (Tag around the entire)

Comment: or delete `</formula1>

<formula1>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

option 1. wrap

xml:

```
<root>
<formula1>
<team name="McLaren">
<driver>
<name>Abcd</name>
<points>112</points>
</driver>
<driver>
<name>Juan Pablo Montoya</name>
<points>60</points>
</driver>
</team>
</formula1>

<formula1>
<team name="McLaren">
<driver>
<name>Kimi Raikkonen</name>
<points>112</points>
</driver>
<driver>
<name>EFGH</name>
<points>60</points>
</driver>
</team>
</formula1>
</root>
```

code:

```
printf("%s\n", ezxml_get(f1, "formula1", 0, "team", 0, "driver", 1, "name", -1)->txt); 
printf("%s\n", ezxml_get(f1, "formula1", 1, "team", 0, "driver", 0, "name", -1)->txt);
```

option 2. unify

xml:

```
<formula1>
<team name="McLaren">
<driver>
<name>Abcd</name>
<points>112</points>
</driver>
<driver>
<name>Juan Pablo Montoya</name>
<points>60</points>
</driver>
</team>

<team name="McLaren">
<driver>
<name>Kimi Raikkonen</name>
<points>112</points>
</driver>
<driver>
<name>EFGH</name>
<points>60</points>
</driver>
</team>
</formula1>
```

code:

```
printf("%s\n", ezxml_get(f1, "team", 0, "driver", 1, "name", -1)->txt); 
printf("%s\n", ezxml_get(f1, "team", 1, "driver", 0, "name", -1)->txt);
```